# Does FTP protocol send the domain you connect to?

Tags: linux, domain, ftp

Im trying to configure proftpd to depend on the host the user connected to, however the server has multiple domains per ip address.

In totalcommander I connect to "domain1.com"
The server is configured for reverse dns "domain2.com"

and %V which is "server DNS NAME" in proftpd returns "domain2.com" (not the one the user connected to)

is it possible to detect what server the user CONNECTED to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. FTP doesn't have the equivalent of HTTP's "host" header. If you want the same FTP server to respond differently when the user connects using different DNS domain names, you will need to assign each host name its own IP

Comment: or force them to put username for example `test@test.com` . thank god i assumed it supports "host headers" before designing my database schema -.-

Comment: There are several ways to work around this, yes: you can use the "account" command, build the user name is ways that will make it unique globally (as you suggested) but it will not help with basic things like server banner or (more problematic) X509 certificate matching if you're using FTP(S).

Comment: As of [RFC 7151](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7151), there is now a `HOST` FTP command for supporting proper name-based FTP virtual hosts, akin to HTTP 1.1's `Host` header.

Comment: @Castaglia Do you know how common it is for clients to support RFC 7151?

Comment: @jonelf Unfortunately I do not know how widespread client support for RFC 7151 is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no Host header in FTP. Microsoft IIS however supports virtual hosts by username ("ftp.domain.tld|username" or "ftp.domain.tld\username").

Comment: It's not clear to me what the FTP client is supposed to do here?